# Can not import modules in vscode

Tags: go

This is what the vscode is warning

```
could not import github.com/gorilla/mux (cannot find package "github.com/gorilla/mux" in any of 
    /usr/local/go/src/github.com/gorilla/mux (from $GOROOT)
```

And these are the only two folders under go which I find out through my terminal:

[image]

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0):

Running `go get -u github.com/gorilla/mux` alone doesn't work.

I found a hacky way to fix the problem.

1. update your GOMODCACHE env `go env -w GOMODCACHE=$GOPATH/src/src`
2. run `go get -u github.com/gorilla/mux`
3. rename the directory mux@version to mux `mv mux\@v1.8.0/ mux`
4. terminate and restart vs code. The error will go away and you will be able to use intelliSense

If there is a better way let me know.

Answer (score -1):

Try running the following command in terminal.

```
go get -u github.com/gorilla/mux
```

This should create src folder for you